# Count unique values of each column of the dataframe Pandas

Tags: pandas, count, unique

I have the following dataframe:

```
index  state  city     gdp    main_sector
1      NY     NYC      1000   services
2      NY     Utica    200    agriculture 
3      CA     LA       1200   tourism
4      CA     SF       800    tourism
5      FL     Miami    1300   services
```

I want to get a list or a table of the columns with unique values:

```
state        3
city         5
gdp          from 200 to 1300
main_sector  3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the columns and apply logic to gdp and find the length of unique values for the others.

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'state': {0: 'NY', 1: 'NY', 2: 'CA', 3: 'CA', 4: 'FL'},
 'city': {0: 'NYC', 1: 'Utica', 2: 'LA', 3: 'SF', 4: 'Miami'},
 'gdp': {0: 1000, 1: 200, 2: 1200, 3: 800, 4: 1300},
 'main_sector': {0: 'services',
  1: 'agriculture',
  2: 'tourism',
  3: 'tourism',
  4: 'services'}})

a= []
b=[]
for col in df.columns:
    if col == 'gdp':
        b.append(col)
        a.append(f'from {df[col].min()} to {df[col].max()}')
    else:
        b.append(col)
        a.append(len(df[col].unique()))
df_new = pd.DataFrame(a,b, columns=['A'])
df_new
```

output:

```
            A
index       5
state       3
city        5
gdp         from 200 to 1300
main_sector 3
```

Comment: There is an error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: I tried with "nunique", but there's another error: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @Guerra try now